# telerik radgrid cannot display all the records

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, radgrid

I need to show all the records in telerik radgrid without pagesize.

By default it's takes only 10 records as pagesize.

How to solve this?

Comment: IMO, the Paging should simply be disabled... show us the `RadGrid` definition in your aspx file.

Comment: By the way you have contradictive properties (`ClientSettings-Scrolling-AllowScroll="true"` and `<ClientSettings>
                           <Scrolling AllowScroll="false"/>
                      </ClientSettings>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you set the PageSize programatically before you bind it?

```
RadGrid1.PageSize = myCollection.Count;
RadGrid1.DataSource = myCollection;
RadGrid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean, but you can query the database and get the nr of items. then set RadGrid1.PageSize = nrOfItems; // as integer

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying `PagerStyle` which might be enabling paging...so don't. Also, don't specify `AllowPaging="True"`.

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="ResultGrid" runat="server" ClientSettings-Scrolling-AllowScroll="true"
      GridLines="Vertical" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#E3EEFE" BorderColor="#E3EEFE"
      HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#E3EEFE" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#C8DCF2" AllowSorting="true"
      AllowPaging="False" AllowFilteringByColumn="false">
          <ClientSettings>
               <Scrolling AllowScroll="false"/>
          </ClientSettings>
 </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Also, a good thing to do is to fix the height of your `RadGrid` to fit your screen. Then use those settings:

```
  <ClientSettings>
       <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="True" />
  </ClientSettings>
```

Should be more user-friendly this way.

Comment: without PagerStyle its display footer i didnt not the fooder. without footer display all record

Comment: @Muthukamatchi : Not sure if I understood, but if you don't want the Footer to display, simply use the `ShowFooter="false"` Property.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to remove paging from the radgrid.  You can do this by setting the "AllowPaging" property on the radgrid in the aspx to be false.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowPaging="false">
</telerik:RadGrid>
```